# How to rewrite that Magento admin action after applying 6788?

Tags: magento

This is my old XML:

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <customactions_menu translate="title" module="giftcard">
            <title>my title</title>
            <sort_order>9999</sort_order>
            <action>giftcard/admin/coupons</action>
        </customactions_menu>
    </menu>
</config>
```

This action does not work any longer after applying patch 6788. How do I have to write that action so it works again?

I already changed my route for the module in config.xml according to the suggestion from https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a module controller structure like following

```
    app\code\local\AW\Followupemail\controllers\Adminhtml\Followupemailadmin\
CouponsController.php
```

The action section will be like following (for index action)

```
<action>adminhtml/followupemailadmin_coupons</action>
```

If you can update your question with your config.xml and directory structure, I can try to help in better manner.